# force i-frame when using mediacodec with createInputSurface

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

is it possible to trigger the encoder to send i-frames when using a surface as the input ?
I know its possible when when queuing input buffers, but I didnt find a way to do so when using createInputSurface .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set flags on the buffers.  This also affects `BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM`, but for that you have the `signalEndOfInputStream()` call.

I frames will be sent every `KEY_FRAME_RATE * KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL` buffers.  (I don't know how firm that is -- I suspect they might appear more or less often in practice.)

Comment: isnt the parameter PARAMETER_KEY_REQUEST_SYNC_FRAME for that ?

Comment: The `setParameters()` API was added in API 19, so won't be available everywhere that Surface input is (added in API 18).  The API only says that it'll try to send a sync frame "soon", so you won't actually have full control over which frames are I-frames.